# ffmpeg: converting to mp4 with error: unsupported codec

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i am converting a videofile with the latest version of ffmpeg in php:

```
exec("ffmpeg -y -i capture.wmv capture.mp4 2>&1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

This is the result:

```
array(21) {
  [0]=>
  string(99) "FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al."
  [1]=>
  string(451) "  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static"
  [2]=>
  string(35) "  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0"
  [3]=>
  string(35) "  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1"
  [4]=>
  string(35) "  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0"
  [5]=>
  string(35) "  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0"
  [6]=>
  string(35) "  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0"
  [7]=>
  string(35) "  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1"
  [8]=>
  string(35) "  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0"
  [9]=>
  string(43) "  built on Jan 24 2013 19:42:59, gcc: 4.4.3"
  [10]=>
  string(34) "Input #0, asf, from 'capture.wmv':"
  [11]=>
  string(60) "  Duration: 00:04:11.45, start: 3.000000, bitrate: 1755 kb/s"
  [12]=>
  string(62) "    Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s"
  [13]=>
  string(82) "    Stream #0.1: Video: wmv2, yuv420p, 1280x720, 1600 kb/s, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc"
  [14]=>
  string(33) "Output #0, mp4, to 'capture.mp4':"
  [15]=>
  string(83) "    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1k tbc"
  [16]=>
  string(62) "    Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x0000, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s"
  [17]=>
  string(15) "Stream mapping:"
  [18]=>
  string(21) "  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0"
  [19]=>
  string(21) "  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1"
  [20]=>
  string(40) "Unsupported codec for output stream #0.1"
}
```

I need a standard mp4-file for playing in web with html5. Where could be the problem? Is the codex not installed? Or is something wrong with the console command?

EDIT:
After using a static build i try to convert a wmv to mp4 with

```
exec("/www/htdocs/xxxx/video/ffmpeg -y -i capture.wmv capture.mp4 2>&1", $output);
```

The result file has a size of only some bytes - this is the output:

```
array(40) {
  [0]=>
  string(77) "ffmpeg version N-49805-gfd6a021 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "  built on Feb 11 2013 05:23:18 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)"
  [2]=>
  string(609) "  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx"
  [3]=>
  string(40) "  libavutil      52. 17.101 / 52. 17.101"
  [4]=>
  string(40) "  libavcodec     54. 91.102 / 54. 91.102"
  [5]=>
  string(40) "  libavformat    54. 62.100 / 54. 62.100"
  [6]=>
  string(40) "  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103"
  [7]=>
  string(40) "  libavfilter     3. 37.101 /  3. 37.101"
  [8]=>
  string(40) "  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100"
  [9]=>
  string(40) "  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102"
  [10]=>
  string(40) "  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100"
  [11]=>
  string(54) "Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo"
  [12]=>
  string(34) "Input #0, asf, from 'capture.wmv':"
  [13]=>
  string(11) "  Metadata:"
  [14]=>
  string(32) "    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000"
  [15]=>
  string(32) "    DeviceConformanceTemplate: @"
  [16]=>
  string(37) "    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.7601.17514"
  [17]=>
  string(23) "    IsVBR           : 0"
  [18]=>
  string(60) "  Duration: 00:04:13.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1742 kb/s"
  [19]=>
  string(90) "    Stream #0:0(ger): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s"
  [20]=>
  string(125) "    Stream #0:1(ger): Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1600 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc"
  [21]=>
  string(35) "[libx264 @ 0x2f082e0] using SAR=1/1"
  [22]=>
  string(63) "[libx264 @ 0x2f082e0] MB rate (3600000) > level limit (2073600)"
  [23]=>
  string(88) "[libx264 @ 0x2f082e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX"
  [24]=>
  string(45) "[libx264 @ 0x2f082e0] profile High, level 5.2"
  [25]=>
  string(684) "[libx264 @ 0x2f082e0] 264 - core 129 r2230 1cffe9f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00"
  [26]=>
  string(33) "Output #0, mp4, to 'capture.mp4':"
  [27]=>
  string(11) "  Metadata:"
  [28]=>
  string(32) "    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000"
  [29]=>
  string(32) "    DeviceConformanceTemplate: @"
  [30]=>
  string(37) "    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.7601.17514"
  [31]=>
  string(23) "    IsVBR           : 0"
  [32]=>
  string(35) "    encoder         : Lavf54.62.100"
  [33]=>
  string(122) "    Stream #0:0(ger): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 16k tbn, 1k tbc"
  [34]=>
  string(90) "    Stream #0:1(ger): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s"
  [35]=>
  string(15) "Stream mapping:"
  [36]=>
  string(39) "  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (wmv2 -> libx264)"
  [37]=>
  string(45) "  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (wmav2 -> libvo_aacenc)"
  [38]=>
  string(31) "Press [q] to stop, [?] for help"
  [39]=>
  string(96) "frame=  158 fps=0.0 q=33.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.10 bitrate=   3.6kbits/s dup=155 drop=0"
}
```

slhck - thanks for your tipps - do you see the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Your FFmpeg version is 0.5.9, which is from a branch that was cut in 2009 (!). Chances are the problem is due to the ancient release and there's no point trying to troubleshoot something which is entirely unsupported.  As far as I can tell FFmpeg can't find a proper audio codec to encode the video with. You don't have any external AAC or MP3 encoder as well.

In any case: **Install a newer version.** Do this by either [compiling it yourself](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), or [downloading a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

---

To produce a HTML5-ready MP4 video, you'd probably explicitly choose an H.264-encoded video with the Baseline profile (to suit mobile devices) and AAC audio:

```
ffmpeg -i capture.wmv -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k out.mp4
```

To change the video quality, add the `-crf` option, with a value between 18–28 (23 is default). Lower means better quality. See the [x264 Encoding Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) on the FFmpeg Wiki for more info.

Your video should contain the MOOV atom at the beginning of the file, which would allow your users to start streaming the contents immediately (otherwise they'd have to download the entire file). You can set this while encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i [stuff from above…] -movflags faststart out.mp4
```

---

If you have FFmpeg with FAAC support (check with `ffmpeg -codecs | grep libfaac`), you can also use the following, similar to above:

```
ffmpeg -i -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a libfaac -q:a 100 out.mp4
```

Here, you'd get VBR AAC audio of better quality instead of the fixed bitrate stream above. The quality is in percent, and 100 is the default.

Comment: Thanks man for detailed information! I told my hoster to install the latest version...after reinstalling you get feedback from me!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can use a static build without any installation or compiling (thus, without root access). You just download the archive, extract it, and use the `ffmpeg` binary that's contained within.

Comment: It seems that my hoster has not the ability to install the latest version, so I downloaded the latest static build: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/
But know: What to do after uploading (2 files, ffmpeg and ffprobe) with FTP in the directory, where my php-scripts are? how can i include it in the script and how can i run the commands? thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to point `exec()` to the path of that file, i.e. not `exec("ffmpeg …")`, but `exec("/home/username/downloads/ffmpeg …")` or wherever it is.

Comment: good message: path is correct, bad message: there is an error: Permission denied! Changing CHMOD could be a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any problem with the output, it should work normally. I'll look into it later a little more.

Comment: After a litte bit testing, it seems, that ffmpeg has problems with mpeg4. mp4- and mov-files are not working, but converting to wmv looks good. but the codec is installed, so i dont know...

Comment: Interesting. Consider posting a question on the FFmpeg-user mailing list—maybe you've encountered a bug? Provide them with the full output, and possible a sample input and output file: https://lists.ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user/

Comment: Oh what a f***. I just try using mencoder, which is also installed at the server with version 1.0~rc3+svn20090426. Maybe i am more lucky with that one...